# Are smart meters really dangerous?

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement, safety

It has been announced that we will be getting smart meters installed in our city by our electrical utility (in the US) later this year (2018). A bank of 23 analog electrical meters now sits about halfway down the hallway (inside our building)from my ground story apartment. I have been hearing for years how RF radiation from smart meters is dangerous to our health. Are they really as dangerous as they are made out to be? And if so, what can I do about it?

Comment: I am not sure how there could be 23 meters code limits each feed to 6. The RF energy is less than a cell phone, there are some folks that think 60hz 120v is hazardous. If you are concerned a simple faraday shield will block the RF, this can be made from chicken wire or other metal/ foil mesh that is grounded.

Comment: what organizations are making them out to be dangerous? It's a cell phone that makes sporadic calls to report usage. Furthermore, most non-smart meters made in the last 20 years also have such cellular devices inside; they don't have the same digital real-time circuitry, but the cell-phone radiation they emit is the same (or higher) than smart meters. who benefits from such fear-mongering?

Comment: Ed Beal..I have spoken to our local utility since I posted my question. They will not allow a faraday cage to be mounted on my meter because it will block the transmission of signals from the meter. But she did say that I could have my condo repainted with “EMF paint“ that could help block harmful emissions from the smart meters. I will have to look into that. I did not mention that my building was built in 1977. Perhaps the code was more liberal about how many meters could be attached to each feed back then. Nor was I aware that code now restricts each feed to 6 meters in new construction.

Comment: @EdBeal -- on large multi-meter installs, there will be a whole-building service disconnect upstream of the meters

Comment: Code limits the disconnecting means at each location to 6 I don't know how they could go beyond this limit as it has been code since I can remember, a grounded mesh on the opposite side of the wall will attenuate the EM field behind the meters if you are concerened, the meter dosent need to be fully enclosed to block EM radiation. A metal screen like for a door can be attached to a wall and grounded this will reduce any signal to a very small level and may not be measurable without very high end equipment. The paint can work but not as well as a metal shield (dosent need to enclose the meter)

Comment: @EdBeal Old question, but if you put a single main breaker/switch ahead of all the meters, you can now cut the power to the entire building with one action, so 23 meters is compliant. You don't need to cut power to each unit individually. Bear in mind that attempting to prevent RF leaving the meter enclosure defeats the purpose of smart meters, which is to be read remotely via radio. Your power company will not like this.

Comment: @someonesomewheresupportsmonica the fact is code still requires services to be grouped if going to a single building this has always been code we can start with pictures since you gave no code reference. New code NEC 2020 exhibit 230.1, 230.2  oh heck let’s skip spelling them out because code shows the first 10 exhibits in article 230 as grouping of 6. Each service still requires an individual disconnect or overcurrent protection for each service and that has nothing to do with the question.  going back 3 years to find something ? 230.2.F requires a plaque or directory denoting the service fed

Comment: I just took a video of these 23 smart meters using my “HF35C HF – analyzer”. The reading shows it well above 1500 Micro watts per square meter, which I’m told is the minimum amount that exposes one to cancer risk if given that exposure continuously. But when standing next to the meters, it is often “pinning the needle“ (showing  “1” on the left side of the readout). I do not know how to post this video on this forum. Else I would. I also have some still photographs showing these power meters.

Comment: I just posted that video on YouTube. The title is “23 smart meters installed in our three-story apartment building put out dangerous radiation”.

Answer (score 6):

No.

It's a cellphone radio, of which there are probably another 3+ in your home.

It's also got a switchmode power supply, which there are probably 20+ of in your home.

Comment: the ones in out area don't even use cell phone technology. they somehow communicate over the powerlines

Comment: Actually, they may use a regular internet connection (dialup phone or DSL or cable or FIOS). Whatever connection they use (wired or wireless), if the utility is smart they will have one meter acting as Master and doing all the communication will all the others slaved via Modbus or a similar connection.

Answer (score 1):

There are people who will claim that *anything* with a radio transmitter is dangerous to your health.  Usually without any real evidence.

The meters will be built to comply with the radio transmitter safety standards in your country, just like the mobile phones, WiFi home routers and all the other wireless gadgets that our homes are filled with these days.